# How to show Varnish in netstat

Tags: ubuntu, varnish

I install Varnish on Ubuntu 16.04.1. After I call netstat -nltup to track port, but Vanish is not shown.

[view error image capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ot7jH.png)

How to show Varnish in netstat ?

Help me !!!

Comment: Please consider making sure that Varnish is running. Netstat will only show running processes attached to ports.

Answer (score 1):

first confirm that on which port is your varnish configured

```
ps aux | grep varnish
```

check for -a option should be your desired port for varnish

mine is 80 so below will show the varnish

```
sudo netstat -plant 80 |grep varnish
```

see the result image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e3Mw1.png)